# How to create a patch in TortoiseSVN while no file is checked out?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, patch

I know if some files are checked out (modified) then I could right click on containing folder, then select "create patch". After then I will see list of all checked out files. So I could include them in the patch.
But when no file is checked out, aka everything is committed, create patch window is empty. So the question is how can I create patch from checked-in files? I want to send this patch to colleagues so they can apply them on company svn server.

thanks,

Comment: Patch means diff between two versions. In the case you described, there're local modifications over SVN base.
Which are the two versions you wish to substract?

Comment: There is a svn server in the company that I didn't access to it from home. Once a week, I copy company's repo to home computer via dvd/flash/etc. During the week I have changes in my home source and wish to send them to company's repo via emailing colleagues. I know that git may be a better choice but I have to use SVN only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A unified diff is a patch file.

1. Using TortoiseSVN, right-click on your working folder and select “Show Log”
2. Select the two revisions (Ctrl-Click)
3. Right-click on either of the highlighted revisions and select **“Show differences as unified diff”**

To save the changed files with the folder structure.

1. Using TortoiseSVN, right-click on your working folder and select “Show Log”
2. Select the two revisions (Ctrl-Click)
3. Select **"Compare revisions."**  This would list the modified files between the revisions in a dialog box
4. Select all the files in the dialog that comes up. Right-click on the selected files and select "Export selection to…"

This should export the modified files with the folder structure.

Comment: That seems very good. But 2 problems: 1. If I have several items changed across a folder tree, I'm forced to do this manually on each file. 2. Is there a way to get diff of folder structures? For example directory changes?

Comment: Actually 3 problems... the unified diff display does not seem to support ShiftJIS, so Japanese text becomes mojibake.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is a `diff` between two subversion **revisions**.  Check out the SVN Book's section on [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re09.html) to see how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want colleagues to get the most up-to-date files, they should get it from the svn server using svn-checkout. If for some reason they can't access your svn server, you can also right-click and choose svn-export; this gives you a set of all the files in the containing folder without any of the hidden .svn directories.

Comment: Please notice my comment on the question. Additionally an export is not a good choice for me. Because I want to send just changed files.